# Adding a param to a URL in Python

Tags: python, variables, python-requests

I am looking to add a parameter to a url in python.

```
     playerNumber = mydict['auctionInfo'][0]['tradeId']
     test = requests.get('https://utas.s2.fut.ea.com/ut/game/fifa16/trade/159826040532/bid', headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

I am looking to replace the number `159826040532` with the value of `playerNumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `string.format`:

```
test = requests.get('https://utas.s2.fut.ea.com/ut/game/fifa16/trade/{}/bid'.format(playerNumber), headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```

Or perhaps more clearly:

```
test = requests.get('https://utas.s2.fut.ea.com/ut/game/fifa16/trade/{playerNumber}/bid'.format(playerNumber=playerNumber), headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
```